# Edit multiple values of xml attribute using repl.bat

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to modify multiple XML attribute's value through helper batch file called repl.bat (by dbenham) - download from: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

The following is a short sample of my XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WORKING_PATH" value="C:\Working\" />
    <add key="VALIDATOR_APPLICATION" value="C:\Validator\Apps\Process.exe" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to modify 2 values using attribute names `WORKING_PATH` and `VALIDATOR_APPLICATION`, not by hardcoded values.

Following is a SampleOut.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WORKING_PATH" value="D:\Project\Working" />
    <add key="VALIDATOR_APPLICATION" value="D:\Project\Working\Apps\Process.exe" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I can edit 1 by 1 with help of following command

```bat
type sample.xml | repl "(<add key=\qWORKING_PATH\q value=\q).*?(\q.*>)" "$1D:\Project\Working\$2" X > new.xml

type sample.xml | repl "(<add key=\qVALIDATOR_APPLICATION\q value=\q).*?(\q.*>)" "$1D:\Project\Working\Apps\Process.exe$2" X > new.xml
```

The problem is, If I try to edit in 1 single line command, it perform only last change

```bat
type sample.xml | repl "(<add key=\qWORKING_PATH\q value=\q).*?(\q.*>)" "$1D:\Project\Working\$2" | repl "(<add key=\qVALIDATOR_APPLICATION\q value=\q).*?(\q.*>)" "$1D:\Project\Working\Apps\Process.exe$2" X > new.xml
```

The output of above command:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WORKING_PATH" value="C:\Working\" />
    <add key="VALIDATOR_APPLICATION" value="D:\Project\Working\Apps\Process.exe" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to use PowerShell, I require a solution using repl.bat only.

Comment: Why not use Powershell?  Just like Vbscript and Jscript, it has native capability to read and write XML files. Also REPL.bat was deprecated over 3 years ago and was replaced by [JREPL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

Comment: I want to use on my client's server and most of don't have Powershell. Can you help me, how to resolve my issue using JREPL.bat

Comment: If PowerShelll is not installed then I assume the servers are Window 2003 server. 2008 server and beyond should have Powershell installed by default. Regardless you can still use Vbscript or Jscript. Also I gave you the link to where JREPL is maintained by the developer. Do you think you might get better help posting your question over on that forum?